# Apache 2.4 when establish a conenction after 30s apache will send a syn ack

Tags: apache, redhat

I wrote a script to establish a connection to apache(just TCP connection) and after established 30s apache  will send a syn ack.
Is the pdu a keep-alive heart beat?
the version is apache 2.4.6 os redhat 6.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just TCP heart beat pdu.